# Issue with Apollo Client cache on a react app

Tags: reactjs, caching, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm struggling with an issue when fetching an endpoint that, based on a category, returns a list of articles.

I have set up a React app with an apollo client that wraps everything (`index.tsx`):

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: myurl,
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </ApolloProvider>
  </ThemeProvider>,

  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Then I have a list of `<Link to={news/${cat}} />` in the menu and when I click on the menu it navigates to `news/1234` correctly.

From the page, I get the category I need and then use it as a variable for my graphql query.

Since I have the client wrapping the whole application, I use `ApolloConsumer` to pass down the client like this:

```
const CategoryArticlesList = ({ location, match }: RouteChildrenProps) => {
  return (
    <ApolloConsumer>
      {(client) => {
        return (
          <ListAllArticles location={location} match={match} client={client} />
        );
      }}
    </ApolloConsumer>
  );
};
```

and then, from `<ListAllArticles>` component, I have this simplified piece of code:

```
const getNewsBycategory = gql`
  query($page: Int, $cid: String) {
    News(page: $page, categoryId: $cid) {
      results {
        category
        category_id
        title
        date
        body_preview
        is_published
        thumbnail_s
        id
      }
      extra {
        pagination {
          total_items
          limit
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;


const pageToFetch = "1"
const categoryId = match.params.categoryId || "1234";

  const variables = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      page: pageToFetch,
      categoryId: categoryId,
    }),
    [categoryId, pageToFetch]
  );

  const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(getNewsBycategory, {
    variables: { ...variables },
  });
```

when I change the page, the category in the URL changes, the query is performed with a new and updated categoryID variable (I checked the network tab) but the results are the same as before.

I think it's a caching issue, so I tried to change to both `"no-cache"` and `"network-only"` the `fetchPolicy`, but I have the same issue.

Can you please suggest why this is happening and how can I overcome this?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help/advice

Comment: Have you estabished <Route /> components?

Comment: yes routing works fine on all the other pages as well

Comment: When you say the results are the same as before -- do you mean the component is not rerendering, or the data returned over the network is the same?

Comment: Keep the fetchPolicy to "network-only", and take a look at the cache using Apollo devtools after navigating to the new route...could be helpful

Comment: thanks for suggesting apollo devtools. When i say the result is the same as before i mean the network returns the same data, like the category is not taken into account at all

Comment: Have you logged what's happening on server? not adding up that you're passing query over network with new category variable and exact data is returned.

Comment: tried the same query with graphql playground (with the new category as well) and the returned data is correct from there, so the query i suppose is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224569/discussion-between-greg-brodzik-and-nick).

Comment: you don't need ApolloConsumer, useQuery hook works with client directly .. you don't need memo ... you can pass `{
      page: pageToFetch,
      categoryId: categoryId,
    }` directly in useQuery variables ... if you checked request variables then check response, too - is it correct?

Comment: i did tried without memo as well as without consumer
the query runs with the right variables but the result from the query is wrong. Same query and same variables from the playground returns correct result

Comment: memo/consumer was about coding practices ... probably not related to the problem ... compare [at network level] detaily headers/body with playground's ... cache/proxy? sth between FE and BE?

Comment: I think it's a cache problem but I don't know how to overcome this. The result is something like data: {results: [{}], extra: [{}]} which can be why (if caching is the problem) the automatic typename (if i understood it correctly) did not work as it should. I tried also to tell him to use the id from inside the results object but again nothing changed. Can this be somehow related?

Comment: can't you just write if RAW network response is ok for RAW network requested variables ? ... 99,9% you're doing something wrong, like console.log not updated state data instead of fresh 'data'

Comment: the issue here is that the RAW response is not correct either from my app, but it is from the playground
looks like there's some cache somewhere that, even if I say just use the network, still returns old data for new variables (on the request as well)

Comment: raw network response can't be a cache problem as it is before reaching it

Comment: the question is why API response differs for properly passed (the same as in playground?) variables (checked in raw network request/headers) - auth reasons? ... show network request+response for app and playground ... network, not apollo dev, not console.logs

Comment: ok i found the issue. Check my own answer to the question, and thanks a lot for the patience anc support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I managed to find the issue.

I was calling my query like this:

```
export const query = gql`
  query($page: Int, $cid: String) {
    News(page: $page, categoryId: $cid) {
      results {
        category
        category_id
        title
        date
        body_preview
        is_published
        thumbnail_s
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

As you can see, I a variable $cid passed down to categoryId (required with this name for the query on the server).
I thought that I could have the name that i wanted for that variable, but it turned out that using the variable as $cid and not $categoryId didn't send out the variable in the query.

Changing my query to look like this:

```
export const getNewsBycategory = gql`
  query($page: Int, $categoryId: String) {
    News(page: $page, categoryId: $categoryId) {
      results {
        category
        category_id
        title
        date
        body_preview
        is_published
        thumbnail_s
        id
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

fixed the problem.

I didn't know about this variable naming thing until now, as strangely enough from the network I could see the variable been sent out, but only debugging the server I managed to figure out it wasn't really being sent out in the end

Comment: it could work with variables containing 'cid' property ... variables must match first brackets args, not the second ones